# How to vectorize an SQL update query in R

Tags: sql, r

I have the following zoo object (res)

```
           column1 column2 column3
2015-12-30  3.2735  2.3984  1.1250
2015-12-31  2.5778  1.8672  1.1371
2016-01-01  3.3573  2.4999  1.1260
2016-01-04  3.3573  2.4999  1.1463
```

and I would like to produce a vectorized update query.

```
UPDATE table SET column1=3.2735, column2=2.3984, column3=1.1250 WHERE dt = '2015-12-30';
UPDATE table SET column1=2.5778, column2=1.8672, column3=1.1371 WHERE dt = '2015-12-31';
```

etc.

I was able to do something similar previously for an INSERT query

```
sColumns <- paste0("dt, index, ", paste0(colnames(res), collapse=", "))
sValues = apply(data.frame(paste0("'", index(res), "'"), paste0("'", index, "'"), coredata(res)), 
                 1 , paste, collapse = ",")
sql <- paste0("INSERT INTO table (", sColumns, ") VALUES (", sValues, ")")
```

which was considerably easier because all column names were grouped, and all values were grouped.  For an UPDATE query, I have to combine alternately columns and fields.

So far, I have the following:

```
sColumns <- paste0(colnames(res), "=")
tmp <- paste(c(matrix(c(sColumns, res[1, ]), 2, byrow = T)), collapse = ", ")
tmp <- gsub("=, ", "=", tmp)
```

Which produces (for one row), output like:

```
[1] "column1=3.2735, column2=2.3984, column3=1.125"
```

Can anyone provide guidance as to how I can use something like apply() to do this for all rows of 'res'?

Comment: Which RDMS are you connecting to: MySQL, SQLite, etc? Will there be more than 3 columns? Depending on API package, you can bulk update data frame in one command even specifying index key and column data types. Sometimes even a staging temp table might come in handy to use with an `INSERT` query for final migration.

Comment: I am using a Postgres database on AWS.  The package I am using is RPostgreSQL.  I've seen various bulk update functions, but none that work with a postgres db.  Would love to know if there are any.  For now, the below works for me, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Try this:

```
library(zoo)

sapply(1:nrow(res), function(i) paste0(
         "UPDATE table SET ", 
         toString(paste0(names(res), "=", coredata(res)[i, ])), 
         " WHERE dt='", time(res)[i], "'"))
```

giving the following character vector:

```
[1] "UPDATE table SET column1=3.2735, column2=2.3984, column3=1.125 WHERE dt='2015-12-30'" 
[2] "UPDATE table SET column1=2.5778, column2=1.8672, column3=1.1371 WHERE dt='2015-12-31'"
[3] "UPDATE table SET column1=3.3573, column2=2.4999, column3=1.126 WHERE dt='2016-01-01'" 
[4] "UPDATE table SET column1=3.3573, column2=2.4999, column3=1.1463 WHERE dt='2016-01-04'"
```

**2)** And a variation giving the same result:

```
sapply(unname(split(res, time(res))), function(z) paste0(
    "UPDATE table SET ", 
    toString(paste0(names(z), "=", z)), 
    " WHERE dt='", time(z), "'"))
```

**Note 1:** If your table is not too large then you could alternately consider reading it into R, performing the update in R and then writing it back.

**Note 2:**  Here is the input shown reproducibly:

```
Lines <- "Date column1 column2 column3
2015-12-30  3.2735  2.3984  1.1250
2015-12-31  2.5778  1.8672  1.1371
2016-01-01  3.3573  2.4999  1.1260
2016-01-04  3.3573  2.4999  1.1463"

library(zoo)
res <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
 foo <- apply(res,1, function(x){
   sprintf("%s = %f", names(x),x)
 }) 

lapply(colnames(foo), function(nn) {
    sprintf("UPDATE table SET %s WHERE dt = \'%s\'",
            paste(foo[,nn], collapse=","),
            nn)
 })
```

which gives:

```
[[1]]
```

[1] "UPDATE table SET column1 = 3.273500,column2 = 2.398400,column3 = 1.125000 WHERE dt = '2015-12-30'"

[[2]]
[1] "UPDATE table SET column1 = 2.577800,column2 = 1.867200,column3 = 1.137100 WHERE dt = '2015-12-31'"

[[3]]
[1] "UPDATE table SET column1 = 3.357300,column2 = 2.499900,column3 = 1.126000 WHERE dt = '2016-01-01'"

[[4]]
[1] "UPDATE table SET column1 = 3.357300,column2 = 2.499900,column3 = 1.146300 WHERE dt = '2016-01-04'"

Comment: Ah yes.  Thanks.  Fixed.

Comment: This gives the format I was looking for, but as a list.  I accepted the below answer as it was more compact, and formatted as a vector.